# Can't install torch (windows)

Tags: python, windows, pip, pytorch, pypy

I am trying to install torch using pypy. when I run `pypy -m pip install torch`, I get this error:

> ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement torch (from versions: none)
> ERROR: No matching distribution found for torch

Why is this happening, and how can I successfully install torch?

I want to install torch (above 1.6.0), I can't

Comment: https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/17835 still is open.

Comment: it is just this:  `pip install torch`

Comment: Hi @D.L, unfortunately I am trying to install it using pypy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pytorch is not compatible with PyPy. Support can be tracked on [this pytorch issue](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/17835). If it would install and run, what benefit would you expect? Have you profiled a pytorch project to see how much time is spent in pure-python code? The PyPy JIT cannot look inside C/C++/CUDA code, and [the cpyext interface code](https://www.pypy.org/posts/2018/09/inside-cpyext-why-emulating-cpython-c-8083064623681286567.html) to interact with the Python C-API is about 4x slower than CPython, so until [HPY](https://hpyproject.org/) is more heavily used I would not expect any performance gain when using PyPy.

Answer (score 0):

try:

`pip3 install torch`

`pip install pytorch`

Answer (score 0):

Do you have python version 3.11?. If yes, try using a lower version. It doesn't work with Python 3.11. When I had anaconda installed with Python 3.9, it worked fine, but when I updated python version to 3.11, I was unable to install it and was getting the same error.